# Should i keep libcurl as static library or as DLL in WIN environment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, libcurl

Is keeping libcurl as static library is best or keeping it as dll is best?

I have an embedded application which has some http transfers so i am using curl.

Since I am building the libcurl as static library it contributes to the size increase of my executable. (I am also linking with openSSL as i need support for HTTPS transfers)

Once i launch application it takes considerable time to show the application loaded. (might get into a situation where user clicks multiple times thinking they have not clicked the exe)

If i keep libcurl as a DLL will that help? if so are there any place where can i directly download the libcurl as DLL with SSL support would be really helpful

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried (a) how much size the static libcurl adds to your app, (b) how much (if at all) faster the startup is when not linking statically? Actually trying it will give more reliable results than any theory-crafting we can do on here.

Comment: There are so many different factors that could be affecting load time in your specific application, that there's really no way anyone could give a sensible answer to this question. As us2012 suggests, you'll just need to try it yourself. Try [this link](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/visual_studio.pdf) with regards to obtaining dynamically linking to libcurl.

Comment: For some reason my static library stands at size 5000 kb.<b> I am also  thinking in parallel that my openssl library can also indirectly contribute to size increase.... i am thinking loud here...

Comment: Well, 5MB are hardly a problem for systems these days. I'm not saying the size is unrelated to your loadup delays, but it's not the primary cause.

Comment: But i will be loading my exe in a cd-rom so hypothetically we are thinking if my executable size is less it can reduce the lag time to load the application between user clicking on the exe and loading the applicatoin.